# Cannot change the back color of a button via a custom method

Tags: .net, vb.net, colors, subroutine, backcolor

Here is my code that should change the back color of any of my buttons, but it doesn't work and I don't have any idea what's wrong:

```
Public Sub color(ByVal backcolor As System.Drawing.Color)
    backcolor = Drawing.Color.CadetBlue
End Sub
```

And here is how I call it when a button was clicked. It should change the back color of `Button1`, but it doesn't. Am I doing it right or am I missing something?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    color(Button1.BackColor)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub color(ByVal btn As Control, ByVal clr As System.Drawing.Color)
    btn.BackColor = clr
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    color(Button1, Drawing.Color.CadetBlue)
End Sub
```

Or

```
Public Sub color(ByVal btn As Control)
    btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.CadetBlue
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    color(Button1)
End Sub
```

That works with any control (Textboxes, Labels e.t.c)

Comment: Actually this is a much better solution. As you say it works for any control, and passing the control's name only is simpler! +1

Comment: I don't really understand your edit. If he wants to change to the same back color every time it's superfluous to add another parameter. I think that you should give your edit as a second option instead, thus keeping both the codes.

Comment: See his comment on the other answer. Didn't i understand right? He says: `that works but i have many buttons to change with different color`

Comment: But he also says that he wants to _"just call the function and enter the button name"_. Which is only possible if you use a predefined color. -- Well whad'ya know? The question is a bit unclear anyway. :)

Comment: Ok i will add that too.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Drawing.Color` is a value type (structure).  When you pass it to your `color` method, only a copy is passed and your method only changes the copy.  You should change your Sub to a Function and return the color and assign it to the button's `BackColor` property:

```
Public Function color() As System.Drawing.Color
    Return System.Drawing.Color.CadetBlue
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button1.BackColor = color()
End Sub
```

Although that function doesn't add any value.  You should probably just set the color directly:

```
Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CadetBlue
```

Per @VisualVincent's comment, you can use `ByRef` in your Sub:

```
Private Sub ChangeColor(ByRef c As System.Drawing.Color)
    c = Color.CadetBlue
End Sub
```

Comment: He could also use `ByRef`.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Thanks, I wasn't sure that would work on a property.  I was just testing that!

Comment: @jacobDenis : And your point is? His edit does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method to do this. Create a **public module** as follows:

```
Public Module Module1    
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub SetBackColourToCadetBlue(aButton As Button)
    'Use the following line for Telerik Button
    'Public Sub SetBackColourToCadetBlue(aButton As Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton) 
        aButton.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue
    End Sub
End Module
```

The you can just call the following to set the backcolor of any button:

```
Button1.SetBackColourToCadetBlue()
```

Comment: An even better solution, IMO! :)

Comment: how  can i change this "btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.CadetBlue"  
to telerik radbutton setting

Comment: If you are using a third party button, on this part `aButton As Button` you need to change `Button` to `Telerik.Button` or whatever it is called - think it might be `RadButton`

Comment: @MattWilko thanks for the idea and that do it.  i just made some few changes.

Comment: `Imports Telerik.WinControls.UI`
then
`byval button as radbutton` and it works